# Why does adding "es-2015" to my Babel preset caused "exports is not defined" in this basic app?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

I am setting up a boilerplate running Gulp with Babel. I have created 2 simple files (`app.js` and `Caller.js`) to test the environment.

Caller.js:

```
export default class Caller {
    constructor() {
        //
    }

    SayHello() {
        alert("Hello!!");
    }
}
```

App.js:

```
import Caller from './Caller.js';

let x = new Caller();
x.SayHello();
```

`App.js` is referenced in `index.html` along with:

```
<script src="/js/Caller.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

My Gulp task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('js', () => {
    pump([
        gulp.src(src.js),
        plumber(err => console.error(err)),
        babel({ presets: ['es2015', 'es2017'] }),
        gulp.dest(dest.js),
        browserSync.stream()
    ]);
});
```

Note: I am trying to be as supportive of older browsers as possible, so I want to include ES2015.

What I find is that when I include es2015, rather than es2017 alone, I get the following errors:

> ReferenceError: exports is not defined
>
> ReferenceError: require is not defined

My understanding is that it is possible to transpile this code into ES2015 compatible code, yet if I remove ES2015 from the Babel presets in Gulp it works fine.

Why?

Comment: Babel converts ES6 modules to CommonJS modules (`require`, `module.exports`) by default. Browsers don't support CommonJS.

Comment: So... how then can I get Babel to convert my code into something that browsers can read?